# How to retrieve a specific dataBinding from MultiBindingExpression?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

In my application I retrieve binding from one object and assign it to another. And some objects has *MultiBinding*  instead. And I want to retrieve a specific binding. How do I do that?

For non multi-bindings I use the following code:

```
Label lbl = (Label)sender;
BindingExpression bindingExpression = lbl.GetBindingExpression.(Label.ContentProperty);
Binding parentBinding = bindingExpression.ParentBinding;
path = parentBinding.XPath.ToString();
label.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, parentBinding);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. I couldn't get binding directly from label, but I was able to use *BindingOperations.GetMultiBindingExpression* static method to retrieve *MultiBindingExpression* and then getting the right Binding.

Here is code for that:

```
MultiBindingExpression multiBindingExpression = BindingOperations.GetMultiBindingExpression(lbl, Label.ContentProperty);
Binding parentBinding = ((BindingExpression)multiBindingExpression.BindingExpressions[1]).ParentBinding;
```